# My training and cross validation set aren't matching

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear

[image: This is my Iterations Vs Cost graph, the cost is inversely proportional to the number of iterations. As the iterations increase, the cost decreases, as it ideally should when applying linear regression.]
[image: This is my hypothesis for the same problem. I don't have much experience but I do think that it fits the set pretty well. Please correct me if I'm wrong here too.]

I'm new to machine learning and currently I'm doing linear regression. I split my training set into the cross validation set, the test set and the training set. The hypothesis that you see here, is of the training set. My question is, even though the model fits good and the cost is minimizing with iterations then why aren't my cross validation answers matching?

Comment: where is validation set?

Comment: I just took input values of it 1 by 1 and checked. The answers didn't match.

Comment: It's better to plot train and validation sets on the same plot and show us how bad it is.